# OpenWeather API - Pulling JSON data out

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

I'm writing a little JavaScript to pull information from JSON that contains name, longitude, latitude and openweather API call. What I need is to get the API information out of the API call into the HTML page so you can get the weather forecast for each information. I have the two elements working separately but can't work out how to get them working together.

Help please? :-)

**Sample API Weather from d.weather**

```
 api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecase?lat=50.8609&lon=-0.08014&&units=metric
```

**HTML page for pulling the openweather JSON data**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Weather</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.7.0/jquery-ui.js" ></script>

<script>
function getWeather(callback) {
    var weather = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=51.5072&lon=0.1275&units=metric';
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: weather,
      success: callback
    });
}

// get data:
getWeather(function (data) {
    console.log('weather data received');
    console.log(data.list[0].weather[0].description); 
    console.log(data.list[0].weather[0].main);  
});

getWeather(function (data) {
    document.write('weather data received');
    document.write('<br>');
    document.write(data.list[0].weather[0].description);
    document.write('<br>');
    document.write(data.list[0].weather[0].main);
    document.write('<br>');
    document.write(data.list[0].main.temp);
    document.write('<br>');
    document.write(data.list[0].main[0].dt_txt);
    document.write('<br>');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Html page for pulling the JSON data**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script> 
<!-- Javascript -->

<script type="text/javascript">
function loadUrl(newLocation){
    window.location = newLocation;
    return false;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#btn382").click(function(){       
        /* set no cache */
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        $.getJSON("weather.json", function(data){
            var html = [];

            /* loop through array */
            $.each(data, function(index, d){           
                html.push("Team : ", d.Teams, ", ",
                          "Long : ", d.Long, ", ",
                          "Lat : ", d.Lat, ", ",
              "Weather : ", d.Weather, "<br>");        
            });


            $("#div381").html(html.join('')).css("background-color", "orange");
        }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ /* assign handler */
            /* alert(jqXHR.responseText) */
            alert("error occurred!");
        });
    });
});
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<a name="#ajax-getjson-example"></a>
<div id="example-section38">   
    <div>Football weather</div>
    <div id="div381"></div>
    <button id="btn382" type="button">Team location</button>
</div>
```

weather.json

```
{
    "Teams":"Wycombe Wanderers",
    "Long":-0.800299,
    "Lat":51.6306,
    "Weather":"  api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=51.6306&lon=-0.800299&mode=html"
  },
  {
    "Teams":"Livingston",
    "Long":-3.52207,
    "Lat":55.8864,
    "Weather":"  api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=55.8864&lon=-3.52207&mode=html"
  },
  {
    "Teams":"Brighton and Hove Albion",
    "Long":-0.08014,
    "Lat":50.8609,
    "Weather":"  api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=50.8609&lon=-0.08014&mode=html"
  },
```

Comment: Can you add these to a jsfiddle?

Comment: Wait, where are you getting `teams` from? That won't be in the weather data. Do you mean `city`?

Comment: Hi Andy, teams are coming from json file which I have manually entered that field

Comment: But somewhere here you seem to merging the weather json and the team json, but I don't see where that's happening.

Comment: I have the two html working in theory as separate pages, team json should be the manual file from the second html page whereas weather json is the api data call I believe

Comment: How are the two sets of data related? Are you linking the teams and weather by city? Until you know that, you won't be able to loop through the datasets to access the information. And for each team you'll need to do a separate API call to get the weather for that city.

Comment: I think I have the weather function working in the first html page which pulls data from the api url so I was hoping that as I have the api url in the other html page I could merge the first function into the second page? maybe?

Comment: @Grimlockz Just a note: I would suggest not to call the open weather api directly but to cache the results yourself on your server. That would make your service more stable an reliable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have the basics that should help you on your way. It's a mashup of your two pages.

First I amended your `getWeather` function to call for the weather rather than the forecast. It accepts a `city` parameter and appends that parameter to the data before the callback is called.

```
function getWeather(city, callback) {
  var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: url,
    jsonCallback: 'jsonp',
    data: { q: city },
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        data.city = city;
        callback(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Here, in lieu of your teams JSON I made one up in the form of a JS object, with Arsenal and Liverpool and their corresponding cities as the data. The function loops over the object, extracts the city name and passes it to `getWeather`. The data is returned and appended to the div.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#btn382").click(function () {

    var teams = {
      arsenal: { city: 'london' },
      liverpool: { city: 'liverpool' }
    };

    for (var team in teams) {
      var city = teams[team].city;
      getWeather(city, function(data) {
        var html = [];
        html.push('<div>')
        html.push('City: ', data.city, ', ');
        html.push('Lat: ', data.coord.lat, ', ');
        html.push('Lon: ', data.coord.lon, ', ');
        html.push('Weather: ', data.weather[0].description);
        html.push('</div>')
        $("#div381").append(html.join('')).css("background-color", "orange");
      });
    }

  });
});
```

Hopefully this will give you a few ideas about how to tackle this project.

[See it working here.](http://jsfiddle.net/a5Dqv/1/)

Comment: Andy thanks for all your help I can see what you have and its a great help - I've added the weather.json so you can see what I was trying to do

Comment: If this is the best answer, can you click the tick?

Comment: @Grimlockz, I've updated the fiddle with code related to the team info you added. I haven't updated the answer.

Comment: amazing - thanks for your help on this - I love jsfiddle.net btw

Answer (score 0):

I have made a complete example. For me this worked:

**HTML file:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery Ajax</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ajx-json-styles.css">

      <script>
        function displayParsedData(data){
          /* Working with the 'data' object (not string) here, now we can access the different properties available.*/
          text = '<b>Name: </b>' + data.list[0].name + '<br/>';
          text += '<b>message: </b>' + data.message + '<br/>';
          text += '<b>Current Temperature: </b>' + data.list[0].main.temp + ' F<br/>';
          text += '<b>Weather Conditions: </b>' + data.list[0].weather[0].description + '<br/>';
          $('#parsed_json').append(text);
        }
      </script>

      <script>
        function test1() {
          getWeather(function (data) {
              $("#raw_json").html('<h2>callback</h2><pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) + '</pre>');
              displayParsedData(data);          
          });
        }

        function getWeather(callback) {
          var weather = 'http://openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/city?lat=8.2924495&lon=-62.7373258';
          $.ajax({
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: weather,
            success: callback
          });
        }
      </script>

      <script>
        function test2() {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'http://openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/city?lat=8.2924495&lon=-62.7373258',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType:"jsonp",
            success: function(data) {
              $("#raw_json").html('<h2>$.ajax</h2><pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) + '</pre>');
              displayParsedData(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
              alert( "error: " + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
          });
        }
      </script>    

      <script>
        function test3() {
          $.getJSON('http://openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/city?lat=8.2924495&lon=-62.7373258&callback=?', function(data) {
              $("#raw_json").html('<h2>getJSON</h2><pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) + '</pre>');
              displayParsedData(data);
            })
          .done(function() {
            alert( "second success" );
          })
          .fail(function() {
            alert( "error" );
          });
        }
        /*$.getJSON('http://openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/city?lat=13.3428&lon=-6.2661&cnt=10&callback=?', function(data) { console.log(data); });*/
      </script>

      <script>
      $(document).ready(function (){
          $("#btn382").click(function(){       
              /* set no cache */
              $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

              $.getJSON("weather.json", function(data){
                  for (var team in data) {
                    var html = [];
                    html = '<div class="item"><b>Team: </b>' + data[team].Teams + '<br/>';
                    html += '<b>Lat: </b>' +data[team].Lat + '<br/>';
                    html += '<b>Lon: </b>' + data[team].Lon + '<br/>';
                    html += '<b>Weather: </b>' + data[team].Weather + '<br/></div>';
                    $("#div381").append(html);
                  }
              })
              .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ /* assign handler */
                  /* alert(jqXHR.responseText) */
                  alert("error occurred!");
              });
          });
      });
      </script>

    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="example-section38">   
        <div>Otra fuente</div>
        <div id="div381"></div>
        <button id="btn382" type="button">Team location</button>
      </div>

      <div id="raw_json"></div>
      <div id="parsed_json"></div>

      <button onclick="test1();">callback</button>
      <button onclick="test2();">$.ajax</button>
      <button onclick="test3();">getJSON</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

**weather.json**

```
    [
    {
      "Teams":"Wycombe Wanderers",
      "Lon":-0.800299,
      "Lat":51.6306,
      "Weather":"  api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=51.6306&lon=-0.800299&mode=html"
    },
    {
      "Teams":"Livingston",
      "Lon":-3.52207,
      "Lat":55.8864,
      "Weather":"  api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=55.8864&lon=-3.52207&mode=html"
    },
    {
      "Teams":"Brighton and Hove Albion",
      "Lon":-0.08014,
      "Lat":50.8609,
      "Weather":"  api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=50.8609&lon=-0.08014&mode=html"
    }
]
```

---

**ajx-json-styles.css**

```
#raw_json {
    border:1px solid #333;
    background-color:#ccc;
    padding: 2em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
}
#parsed_json {
    padding:2em;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
}
h2 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.item{
    padding-bottom: 0.25em;
    padding-top: 0.25em;
    background-color: #E9BB18;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

---

Answer (score -1):

why don't you use xml instead of json it's easy to parse, i use it in my website [weathercase](http://www.weathercase.net) , try api provider yr.no

Comment: Because JSON is much faster to parse. Almost 10 times the efficiency.

Comment: Any proofs that JSON is faster

Comment: Here is an experiment in Python that illustrates my statement: https://github.com/concolato/data_processing/tree/master/imageXMLtoCVSTestPY, and since Python is a C based language, I would expect similar results in C/C++, Java and PHP. But, you can try it in another language to confirm if you like.